# Reading dateformat (AM/PM) csv from IICS to Snowflake TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone has the syntax to read the csv data from IICS to Snowflake.

Error:
TT_11019 There is an error in the port [Record_Date]: The default value for the port is set to: ERROR(Transformation error: IUpdateStrategyNode4).

csv Data: 3/16/2021  12:42:00 PM
3/16/2021  11:27:00 PM

snowflake format:   RECORD_DATE TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

I tried these format but none of them works for me:

to_date(Record_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
to_date(Record_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
to_date(Record_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS')
to_date(Record_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
TO_DATE(REG_REPLACE(Record_Date, '( AM| PM)', ''), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(REG_REPLACE(Record_Date, '( AM| PM)', '')), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))

to_date(Record_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The format should be like this:

```
select to_timestamp('03/16/2021 12:42:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM');
```

where you get:

```
2021-03-16 12:42:00.000
```

When using AM/PM the hour must be under format HH12 not HH24.
Be aware of some incorrect results when using this format, as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#date-formats)

Comment: The data that the IICS mapping is reading from is the csv file that looks like this      
  3/16/2021 12:42:00 PM                                                                                             
  3/16/2021 11:27:00 PM

Comment: The data that the IICS mapping is reading from is the csv file that looks like this
3/16/2021 12:42:00 PM
3/16/2021 11:27:00 PM
3/16/2021 1:20:00 AM ...... the target database is snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

The data that the IICS mapping is reading from is the csv file that looks like this
3/16/2021 12:42:00 PM
3/16/2021 11:27:00 PM
3/16/2021  1:20:00 AM
......
the target database is snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening this in Excel instead of a text editor?  instead of writing it to snowflake first, write it directly to a test flat file. open your file and see the structure of the date it is writing your field as.  Then use that as the To_Date([date field],'FORMAT').  I had to do something similar with an excel file.  writing the file to a test flat file I found the data was actually formatted  10/12/22 6:00 so To_Date([date],'MM/DD/RR HH24:MI') was successfully able to send the data to snowflake as a date field.